# Query XML data in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server, xml, sql-server-2008-r2

I am trying to parse through an XML in SQL Server 2008 R2 and I am having some issues. I am trying to parse through the items for each parent node, but I'm not getting the solution The XML data is below:

```
<MerchantInfo xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Active>true</Active>
  <CreatedDate>2015-04-16T00:00:00+05:30</CreatedDate>
  <CreatedBy>63747</CreatedBy>
  <ModifiedBy>63747</ModifiedBy>
  <ModifiedUserName>charucsrawat@hpcl</ModifiedUserName>
  <MerchantCode>0</MerchantCode>
  <RetailOutletName>Gayatri Automobiles</RetailOutletName>
  <DealerName>Vandana Singh</DealerName>
  <ERPCode>16622710</ERPCode>
  <OwnerID>0</OwnerID>
  <ICICIAcDetailsRequired>false</ICICIAcDetailsRequired>
  <SupplyLocationCode>Mirzapur</SupplyLocationCode>
  <IsLive>false</IsLive>
  <LiveSAM>1</LiveSAM>
  <TestSAM>0</TestSAM>
  <OutletCategory>8001</OutletCategory>
  <HighwayNo>NH7</HighwayNo>
  <HighwayName>Mirzapur Rewa Road</HighwayName>
  <SecurityDeposit>10000</SecurityDeposit>
  <HSDSaleMonthly>200</HSDSaleMonthly>
  <Comments />
  <VerifiedDate>0001-01-01T00:00:00</VerifiedDate>
  <VerifiedBy>0</VerifiedBy>
  <isCloned>false</isCloned>
  <VerifiedByUserName />
  <ApprovedDate>0001-01-01T00:00:00</ApprovedDate>
  <ApprovedBy>0</ApprovedBy>
</MerchantInfo>
```

my code is :

```
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES ('http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"' AS mi)
SELECT 
    T.C.value('mi:erpcode[1]','numeric') as erpcode,
    T.C.value('mi:SecurityDeposit[1]','varchar(50)') AS securitydeposit
FROM ChangeEvent ce
    CROSS APPLY changeddata.nodes('mi/erpcode[1]') AS T(C)
WHERE Ce.EntityTypeId = 2
    AND CAST(Ce.ChangedData AS VARCHAR(MAX)) LIKE '%16622710%'
GO
```

What I am looking for is:

```
erpcode  securitydeposit
16622710  10000
```

Kindly help

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `;WITH XMLNAMESPACES` for this purpose since XML elements involved in the query doesn't use any namespace prefix and the XML document doesn't have defult namespace too.

Also note that XML element/attribute name are case-sensitive (f.e `erpcode != ERPCode`) :

```
SELECT 
    T.C.value('ERPCode[1]','numeric') as erpcode,
    T.C.value('SecurityDeposit[1]','varchar(50)') AS securitydeposit
FROM ChangeEvent ce
    CROSS APPLY ChangedData.nodes('MerchantInfo') AS T(C)
WHERE Ce.EntityTypeId = 2
    AND T.C.value('ERPCode[1]','numeric') = 16622710
```

**[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/c8681/7)**